# Aligning Multiple <img> with float

Tags: css, css-float

I'm having trouble aligning these images. I have seven pictures and I want to align them by using floats and clears. Is there any code in CSS where I exclude an element from being affected from another element's "clear" property? In the picture you can see that I applied "clear: both;" to the webcam picture to let it go down the "Push The Limit" instead of it being right beside -- I dont want the other images to be affected.

[image: I believe the picture explains itself]

Here's my HTML:

```
        <div class="imgContainer">
        <div class="leftImgs">
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/Zotac_1.png" class="gpu"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/webcam.png" class="webcam"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/combs.png" class="combs"></a>
        </div>          
        <div class="centerImgs">
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/monitor.png" class="monitor"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightImgs">
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/kb.png" class="kb"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/headset.png" class="headset"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/mobo.png" class="mobo"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
    .gpu {
    width: 33%;
    margin-bottom: .25%;
    float: left;
}

.webcam {
    width: 16.25%;
    margin-right: .5%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.combs {
    width: 16.25%;
    float: left;
}

.monitor {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.kb {
    width: 16.25%;
    float: right;
}

.headset {
    width: 16.25%;
    margin-right: .5%;
    float: right;
}

.mobo {
    width: 33%;
    margin-top: .25%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: you should also float the wrappers .leftImgs, .centerImgs and .rightImgs

Comment: @KeesvanLierop if I do that, the images would shrink in size and would go all over the place. Picture for reference -- [link] (http://i67.tinypic.com/307vs49.jpg)

Comment: did you try to style wrappers as inline-block: e.g. `.leftImgs, .centerImgs, .rightImgs {display: inline-block; width: 32%;}` Anyway it could be better if you'd post whole css rules

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are styling the individual images and not the containers?

Comment: @Banzay it doesn't work, it aligns the leftImgs and centerImgs but it resizes everything

Comment: @Chris because each image is a link

Comment: do you consider to use bootstrap?

Comment: @Banzay Instructor wont let us use bootstrap for a responsive web design, he's making us use media queries :(

Comment: So along with styles from my comment above you need to change existing rules as follow: change 33% to 98% and 16.25% to 49%

Comment: @Banzay it kinda worked, it's now aligned but there's a whitespace between images. Wont go away with float and inline-block. It's okay now I just found a workaround. White space still there just used the negative margin method because it's the only one working. Anyway, How do I select your comment as the answer? It seems like it Did the job

Comment: I've posted comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style wrappers as inline-block: e.g.

```css
.leftImgs, 
.centerImgs,
.rightImgs {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
}
```

Along with this style you need to change existing rules as follow: change 33% to 98% and 16.25% to 49%. Thereafter it should look much better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sequence of divs:

```
<div class="imgContainer clearfix">
    <div class="leftImgs">
        <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/Zotac_1.png" class="gpu"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/webcam.png" class="webcam"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/combs.png" class="combs"></a>
    </div>          
    <div class="rightImgs">
        <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/kb.png" class="kb"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/headset.png" class="headset"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/mobo.png" class="mobo"></a>
    </div>
<div class="centerImgs">
    <a href=""><img src="Images/Homepage/monitor.png" class="monitor"></a>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
 // **** clearing floats begins **** //
.clearfix:after {
content: "&nbsp;";
font-size: 0;
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden; }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clear { clear: both; }
 // **** clearing floats ends **** //

.leftImgs{ float:left; width:33%; }
.rightImgs{ float:right; width: 16%; }
.centerImgs{ float:none; margin:0 auto; width:51%; }
```

Comment: It resizes all the images, and would look so small

Answer (score 0):

I would properly redesign it all and use Flexbox instead of floating elements.

But if you want to do a quick fix, try to add `vertical-align-top` to the parent containers of your anchor-links *(leftImg, centerImg and leftImg)*.

I don't know how you have styled those, but they could look like this:

```
.leftImgs,
.centerImgs,
.rightImgs {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 33%;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

You can also use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block`

Comment: Same as what I've comment above, It resizes all the images, and would look so small